# Is there any excel-like grid solution for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, excel, angularjs-directive, grid, handsontable

I found ngHandsontable very satisfying.

http://handsontable.com/

However, it does not support inserting columns which Handsontable supports. So I'm wondering if there is any other solution that is similar to ngHandsontable but also supports dynamic columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ng-grid #http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

Comment: @K.Toress Just checked it before I posted the question... Seems it doesn't support inserting columns either, only inline editing.

Comment: Why not bind the columns to an underlying model using ng-repeat? http://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/demo/#/columns-add-remove-column-ng-repeat

Answer (score 4):

[**Angular UI Grid**](http://ui-grid.info/) is the latest and greatest from the [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) team. 
It is not as "Excel like" as Handsontable, but it does support [Adding and Removing Columns](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/113_adding_and_removing_columns).

Comment: Very true. ngHandsontable feels much more like Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Kendo UI have a really decent [spreadsheet widget](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/index) that you can use with AngularJS. It's in Beta as I write but after using it for the first time myself I'd say it was well worth a look at if you need a full featured in browser spreadsheet.

Comment: it says "jQuery Spreadsheet control example". It is not angularjs

Comment: @galets You can use it with angular, the kendo angular directive works, I've demoed it myself.

Comment: Although since I wrote this the spreadsheet widget has become a pro feature so that's worth noting. You have to pay for this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you can opt for a commercial solution you can have a look at **FlexSheet** by Wijmo:

https://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular2/FlexSheetExplorer/FlexSheetExplorer/#/intro

It's available for AngularJS and Angular 2, it supports even formulas and a lot of features for building a good excel sheet.